# How to speed up scaling in android

Tags: android, scaling, android-canvas

Hey I need to scale a bitmap in my application, however scaling is working too slowly, and sometimes I get these random scaling events on the opposite direction. here is my ondraw method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ucsbmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, matrix, mPaint);    
}
```

and my onScale method (part of a SimpleOnScaleGestureListener that handles the scaling of my bitmap)

```
     public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {      
          float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
          float x = detector.getFocusX();
          float y = detector.getFocusY();
          matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, x, y);
          repaint();
          return true;
     }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem not actual in scaling. You accessing disc (`BitmapFactory.decodeResource`) in `onDraw` method - it's really slow action.

Move following code to constructor:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ucsbmap);
```